# Not able to get PyData Berlin 2018 Rasa Chatbot ipynb working

Tags: jupyter-notebook, rasa-core, rasa

I am trying code given at `GitHub - RasaHQ/rasa-workshop-pydata-berlin` and demoed at YouTube. It is not working with the latest rasa core, errors due to policies, custom actions, etc.

I followed tutorials like:

- https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-conversational-chatbot-for-slack-using-rasa-and-python-part-1-bca5cc75d32f,
- https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa-workshop-pydata-berlin and
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3qgWQ-u1lQo

But they do not work with the latest rasa core.

Important steps like how to start rasa core custom actions server, how to supply custom methods, if you are doing Jupyter Notebook, are all unclear.

Is it possible to get the ipynb working with the latest rasa? Also mention the step of how to run the actions server, within ipynb itself.

One more suggestion (for Rasa folks): I would suggest doing regression/smoke testing before changing any APIs/Classes. The test suite should have all the published tutorials, at least the ones by Rasa folks themselves. Only when these passes, the new version should be published. If it does not pass, modified tutorials should be published. This just for a basic sanity check.

Answer (score 2):

In a jupyter notebook you can execute shell commands by adding '!' infront of the command. For example, you can run:

`! rasa train`

This will not work for commands like `rasa shell` or `rasa init` because these commands take input from the user. A hacky way to achieve this with Jupyter notebook is by embedding a terminal there and the running the commands you want to execute:

```
from IPython.display import IFrame
IFrame("http://localhost:8888/terminals/2", width=1000, height=500)
```